# Vertical alignement in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

How can I make buttons like this?

[image]

```
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        JPanel jpB1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel jpB2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel jpB3 = new JPanel();
        JButton jb1 = new JButton("button1");
        JButton jb2 = new JButton("button2");
        JButton jb3 = new JButton("button3");
            ...
        JLabel jl = new JLabel("label");
        ...
        jp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        ...
        jpB1.add(jb1);
        jpB2.add(jb2);
        jpB3.add(jb3);
        ...
        jp.add(jpB1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        jp.add(jpB2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jp.add(jpB3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            ...
```

I tried this code on creating 3 panels and add them to the main panel. It shows two buttons on north and one button on south! Can someone help me?

Comment: You could try a Gird layout, a vertical flow layout, a preferred size border layout, a null layout, a grid bag layout... pretty much any if you work at it.

Comment: I won't click it , but this is : `This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful`

Comment: You don't need so many JPanels. You could just create one with GridLayout, which has one column and three rows, and add your buttons to it.

Comment: Also I don't see a reason for the number of downvotes?

Comment: Please refrain from deleting questions!

Answer (score 3):

Note, the default layout of `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`; a `GridBagLayout` with default constraints is centered in the frame's `BorderLayout.CENTER`. Also, `pack()` the enclosing `Window` and display it last. Using [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) left as an exercise.

Addendum: A useful trick for solving layout problems is setting the background color of an enclosing container to a contrasting color, for example

```
jpB2.setBackground(Color.blue);
```

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Bouton2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int LARGEUR = 400;
        final int HAUTEUR = 300;

        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        JPanel jpB1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel jpB2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JPanel jpB3 = new JPanel();
        JButton jb1 = new JButton("Cliquez ici");
        JButton jb2 = new JButton("Je compte");
        JButton jb3 = new JButton("J'agrandis");

        JLabel jl = new JLabel("0 clic");

        jp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        jpB1.add(jb1);
        jpB2.add(jb2);
        jpB3.add(jb3);

        jp.add(jpB1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        jp.add(jpB2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jp.add(jpB3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        jf.setTitle("Fenêtre Bouton2");
        jf.setContentPane(jp);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setSize(LARGEUR, HAUTEUR);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jf.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```